# Why I am not getting all solutions for $2\cos^2x+3\sin x=0$?

Tags: trigonometry

The question is Find the principle solution for

$$2\cos^2x+3\sin x=0$$

so, $\sin x=\frac{-1}{2}$ and $\alpha=-\frac{\pi}{6}$.

So plugging it in the formula

$$2n\pi+\alpha$$

I am only getting $\frac{11\pi}{6}$ .

My teacher said this form covers all solutions but I am getting only one of the two, Is he wrong?

Comment: what is $\alpha$?

Comment: Could you explain the line "so, $\sin(x)=-1/2$ and $\alpha=-\pi/6$" ?

Comment: The original equation is a quadratic in $\sin x$, and could have two solutions.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I solved a quadratic for sin x and got that and I put -pi/6 as alpha in the formula 2.n.pi+alpha

Comment: @player3236 one solution is 2 which is not possible in the range of sin

Comment: If so, consider $\sin x = \sin (\pi - x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of $\sin x=\sin p$ is $x=n\pi+(-1)^np,n\in\Bbb Z$. Plugging $p=-\pi/6$ gives two principal solutions $2\pi-\pi/6$ and $\pi+\pi/6$.

Comment: I understand sir , but is my formula wrong?

Comment: @JustJohan No, your formula is incomplete. It only considers the solutions of the form $2n\pi+\alpha$ but not those of the form $(2n+1)\pi-\alpha$. Clearly $\sin((2n+1)\pi-\alpha)=\sin(2n\pi+\pi-\alpha)=\sin(\pi-\alpha)=\sin(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$2 \cos^2x+3\sin x=0 \iff 2 \sin^2x-3\sin x-2=0 \implies \sin x = -\frac12$$

which has two families of solutions

$$x=-\frac \pi 6 +2k\pi \quad \lor \quad x=\frac 7 6 \pi +2k\pi$$